# "Session manager must be in idle state when requesting a shutdown"

Tags: xubuntu, shutdown, xfce, logout

I know this is a duplicate but not thread I found on the net solves my problem.
We're running several XUbunutu 16.04 terminals that start into a locked down guest account. One of the system started behaving wierd after being updated  stating when a shutdown/logout is initated that the

> Session manager must be in idle state when requesting a shutdown

I can't find anything in the logfiles but it's no longer possible to shut the system down from the GUI or log the guestuser out of the session.

Does anyone have an idea what can cause this particular problem or can tell me who I should contact that could help?

Best Regards,
expired